# Undefined name 'duplicateItems'. Try correcting the name to one that is defined, or defining the name

Tags: flutter, listview, search

Undefined name 'duplicateItems'.
Try correcting the name to one that is defined, or defining the name.
I have fixed it to another one still stuck with the same problem.

```
class view_problem extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<view_problem> createState() => _view_problemState();
}

class _view_problemState extends State<view_problem> {
  List<problemModel> problemlist = [];
  StreamController _streamController = StreamController();
  Future getAllProblem() async {
    problemlist = await problemcontrollers().getProblem();
    _streamController.sink.add(problemlist);
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) {
      getAllProblem();
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  void _filterSearch(String query) {
    setState(() {
      problemlist = duplicateItems
          .where((item) => item.toLowerCase().contains(query.toLowerCase()))
          .toList();
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not defined duplicateItems in your function or even global variable. You have to define it before using it. Weather duplicateItems is a String, int or some other type code doesn't know so we have to mention define it.In your case it is a list of String I guess as it is a search function so my answer is accordingly.

UPDATED Answer:- Here I have also made a change so that when there is space in the search query it will still give you a valid result and if it help please accept this answer and give an upvote !!

```
void _filterSearch(String query) {
   if (query.isNotEmpty) {
      List<ApptUsersModel> dummyListData = [];
      _dummySearchList.forEach((element) {
        var fullName = (element.firstname!+element.lastname!).trim();
        if (fullName.toLowerCase().contains(query.toLowerCase().replaceAll(' ', '').trim())) {
          dummyListData.add(element);
        }
      });
      Utility.log("Length of dummyListData is --> ${dummyListData.length}");

      setState(() {
        _searchResultList.clear();
        _searchResultList.addAll(dummyListData);
        Utility.log(
            "Length of _searchResultList in if is --> ${_searchResultList.length}");
      });
      return;
    }
  }
```

Comment: I fixed it and stuck here.    A value of type 'List<String>' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'List<problemModel>'.
Try changing the type of the variable, or casting the right-hand type to 'List<problemModel>'.

Comment: Okay so it's expecting the duplicate items to be of type List<problemModel> like Your problemlist so Just refer my updated answer where i have made a similar search function like your and get a reference for your it will be easy.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed it as you suggested and was able to run it.

Comment: @gamedevdover please accept my answer and an upvote would be great, Thanks !!